# Run external program in php repetitive

Tags: javascript, php, c++, exec, setinterval

I want to run a program written with c++ in web server repetitive.
Because there is something that php can't do, but c++ can do it easy.

I searched and found that it could be done by using [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function in php.

I used this in js `setInterval` to run that program every 100ms. 
But it seems that that program runs when web page loads and in js code, I have the same output.

for example, when I want to get current date from c++ program. the cpp code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    cout << 1 + ltm->tm_sec;
    return 0;
}
```

and in `index.php` file I used this for print current second at page every 100ms.

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        var date = "<?php passthru("print_date.exe"); ?>";
        document.write(date + "<br>");
    },100);
</script>
```

but it prints always the same!

Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about javascript or php, but I think it is very likely that there are ways to do whatever you want to do in these languages as well. Maybe you should ask about the exact use case that you have instead. Also do you expect this to run on server- or client-side? You cannot run an executable like this on client-side.

Comment: the php will be executed only _once_ when the javascript is rendered. The javascript setInterval will then always use the same (stored) return of `passthru(...)`. You would have to do an ajax call inside setInterval to make the php script get called multiple times.

Comment: What is that something that php can't do? get the current date??

Comment: But to reach your goal anyway a cronjob would likely be the right choice. It's hard to tell though, because we don't know the usecase of this.

Comment: thanks about answering. the problem is getting custom UDP packet data from local network @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Because php code is executed only 1 time. Use Ajax as an option.

//updated next day.
1. file (index.php)

```
<script>
var aj;

setInterval(function()
{
aj = new XMLHttpRequest();
aj.open('GET',"/print_date.php",false);
aj.onreadystatechange  = processData;
aj.send(null);
},1000);

function processData()
{
var date = '';
if (aj.readyState == 4) 
{
date = aj.responseText;
document.write(date + "<br>")   
}
}
</script>
```

It is very simple synchronous ajax. interval is 1000, not 100, because 1000ms = 1s (C++ program returns time in seconds!).

2) So, print_date.php is

```
<?php 
 error_reporting(0); //because any warning destroys output for ajax
 passthru("print_date.exe");
```

Comment: Could you please provide more complete answer? Perhaps add some code sample? This seems more like a comment.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: it is very simple. i add code, if you dont understand something - ask.